# WiFi Direct: Measure connection strength between peers and GO

Tags: android, signals, wifi-direct

I'm working on Wifidirectdemo and I want to know if there is any form to measure or calculate the strength between the connection of one peer with the Group owner. If that is not possible, is it there any way to know any signal (in Wifidirect matter) from one cellphone itself?

Practically I want to know which is the best device among all peers.